# Sorted array by column sum and excluding the largest sum of each column using Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to sort an array by column sum and delete the largest element of each column then continue the sorting.

```
#sorted by sum of columns
def sorting(a):
   b = np.sum(a, axis = 0)
   idx = b.argsort()
   a = np.take(a, idx, axis=1)
   return a

arr = [[1,2,3,8], [3,0,2,1],[5, 4, 25, 67], [11, 1, 6, 10]]
print(sorting(arr))

Here is the output: 

[[ 2  1  3  8]
 [ 0  3  2  1]
 [ 4  5 25 67]
 [ 1 11  6 10]]
```

I was able to able to find the max of each column and their indexes but I couldn't delete them without deleting the whole row/column. Please any help I am new to numpy!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not very elegant, one way to achieve this would be like this using [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [fancy/advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1,2,3,8], [3,0,2,1],[5, 4, 25, 67], [11, 1, 6, 10]])
```

First get the intermediate array sorted by column sums.

```
arr1 = arr[:, arr.sum(axis = 0).argsort()]
print(arr1)
# array([[ 2,  1,  3,  8],
#        [ 0,  3,  2,  1],
#        [ 4,  5, 25, 67],
#        [ 1, 11,  6, 10]])
```

Next get where the maximas occur in each column.

```
idx = arr1.argmax(axis = 0)
print(idx)
# array([2, 3, 2, 2])
```

Now prepare row and column index arrays to slice from `arr1`. Note that the line to compute `rows` essentially performs a set difference of {0, 1, 2, 3} (in general to number of rows in `arr`) for each element in `idx` above, and stores them along the columns of the `rows` matrix.

```
k = np.arange(arr1.shape[0]) # original number of rows
rows = np.nonzero(k != idx[:, None])[1].reshape(-1, arr1.shape[0] - 1).T
cols = np.arange(arr1.shape[1])
print(rows)
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [3, 2, 3, 3]])
```

Note that `cols` will be broadcasted to the shape of `rows` while indexing `arr1` by them. For your understanding `cols` will look like this to be compatible with `rows`:

```
print(np.broadcast_to(cols, rows.shape))

# array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
#        [0, 1, 2, 3],
#        [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

Basically when you *(fancy)* index `arr1` by them, you get the 0th column for rows 0, 1 and 3; 1st column for rows 0, 1 and 2 and so on. Hope you get the idea.

```
arr2 = arr1[rows, cols]
print(arr2)
# array([[ 2,  1,  3,  8],
#        [ 0,  3,  2,  1],
#        [ 1,  5,  6, 10]])
```

You can write a simple function composing these steps for your convenience to perform the operation multiplie times.

Comment: Sure. Let me know if you find any problem or face any difficulty.

Comment: @Ibrahim: Just wondering, did it solve your problem?